# PHP: How can I capture or trace all methods that were called in single page load?

Tags: php, magento

Let's say that I'm loading some page. This page is using several classes with some methods and variables. How can I trace for example this methods I mean files, lines and times? I was doing some research and I found debug_backtrace function in PHP but I just wonder if there is some other way to do it? Also I would like to adopt this functionality in magento.

Regards,

Comment: you can enable/install `xdebug`. It has very good debugging/profiling capabilities

Comment: look [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) for start..

Comment: In Magento you have profiler that an be used to do profiling.But will not give count for all functions executed still worth doing as it will give lots of details.Debug backtrace will give you a tracelog which is again helpful with debugging magento.

Answer (score 0):

try that - https://github.com/facebook/xhprof

XHProf is a function-level hierarchical profiler for PHP and has a simple HTML based user interface. The raw data collection component is implemented in C (as a PHP extension). The reporting/UI layer is all in PHP. It is capable of reporting function-level call counts and inclusive and exclusive wall time, CPU time and memory usage. Additionally, it supports ability to compare two runs (hierarchical DIFF reports), or aggregate results from multiple runs. Originally developed at Facebook, XHProf was open sourced in Mar, 2009.

very usefull thing!